# Unviersal analytics - Measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

When i look at website data under "audience overview" page , I notice the System section which contains - browser , operating system and service provider.

how to set information for this using measurement protocol , any example or parameter reference for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's sent in the user agent string. There's no public API to override it

Answer (score 0):

You can specify User Agent Override parameters from the API in Measurement Protocol.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ua

Be aware this is subject to change by Google. However, at this time User Agent string CAN be overridden using the public API.